# Почему в этом предложении присутствует запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

"Воздух рядом с ним(,)становится как мед"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Это комментарий к ответу Jim Korbett**

Я **кратко** обозначу основные моменты в нашем диалоге в комментариях (он имеет **принципиальное** значение):

– Розенталь часто говорит об **интонационном** предупреждении при постановке двоеточия. Что он имеет в виду? Например: «Перед второй частью БСП ставится тире, если она имеет изъяснительное значение… причем в первой части не содержится ИНТОНАЦИОННОГО предупреждения о последующем изложении какого-либо факта».

– В справочнике Розенталя полно **некачественных, размытых** формулировок. Здесь как раз **одна из них.** У меня нет особого желания расшифровывать это **священное писание**. Возможно, это **высокий резкий тон**, говорящий о том, что последует **важная, эпическая, захватывающая или изумляющая** информация.  Я так понимаю, что у вас возникают вопросы о постановке двоеточия или тире при изъяснительных отношениях в бессоюзном предложении?

– Вы не так понимаете, но это неважно.  Мне хотелось понять **ваши принципы**, и вот что я могу сказать (окончательный «диагноз»).

– У меня против вас **абсолютный иммунитет** (так что не тратьте напрасно время), но вы, очевидно, рассчитываете на **малознающих** или колеблющихся людей.

Вы точно из той школы, которую я  уже называла: **без правил** (вы их собираетесь толковать по-своему), **без интонационного анализа** (ваши предположения его не заменят), то есть на одном энтузиазме.

Но не ошиблись ли  вы **с аудиторией:** «послушные овцы» сюда не часто заходят, а у школьников, студентов, редакторов-корректоров интересы чисто практические (как пишется и почему так пишется), им **духовные учителя и лидеры** не нужны (здесь я имею в виду ваши предыдущие высказывания о необходимости послушания учителя для учеников).

Что касается постоянных участников форума, то **резко   негативное** суждение в ваш адрес они уже высказали. Спасибо за внимание, отвечать не нужно.

P.S.  Надеюсь, что **участник,** проголосовавший за ответ, сделал это со всей **ответственностью.**

1. **Проблема с лишней запятой** там неясно обозначена и никак не решается.
2. Рассуждения об обособлении определительного оборота не вполне корректны (в приведенном им примере обособление факультативно), а главное, **не связаны** с темой вопроса. Это всего лишь указание на частные детали в конкретном тексте.
3. Но ведь я могу поставить лишнюю запятую и в таком предложении, где подлежащее и сказуемое **не будут разделены**: Рядом с этим удивительным человеком// даже воздух становится как мед.
4. Получив подобную консультацию, автор вопроса **не получает знаний**, а должен будет каждый раз обращаться к своему учителю, то есть **зависеть** от него.

Comment: 1. Тогда и везде можно поставить запятую и 100500 лет думать на ее тайным значением. Может быть, одиночная запятая между подлежащим и сказуемым — это тайный еврейский знак, сигнализирующий о приближении мировых погромов. 2. Поэтому я и сказал: «можно обособить» а не «обязательно обособляется». 3. Можете и будете правы, подлежащее и сказуемое нельзя разделять одиночными запятыми. 4. Я могу дать ссылку на Розенталя на наличие запятой, но не на ее отсутствие.

Comment: Про необходимость духовного учителя. Это очевидно была шутка. Это моя вина: мне следовало помнить, что  филологи не могут в юмор.

Comment: Логическое ударение на зависит от интонации, потому что в различных ситуациях одно и тоже предложение можно произнести абсолютно одинаково, но ударение не изменится. Как вы огибаете в своей голове это безусловное, фактическое, эмпирическое доказательство?

Comment: Про обособленный оборот еще раз. Это просто прибавочная информация к вопросу, ничего более.

Answer (score 3):

Потому что кто-то допустил ошибку. Подлежащее и сказуемое не отделяется друг от друга запятой. Между ними может стоять обособленный оборот или часть сложного предложения, но не одиночная запятая. Оборот места «рядом с нами» можно было бы обособить, если бы он был бы более распространенным(более чем предлог, частица и словосочетание). Воздух, рядом с красными игральными автоматами, становится как мед.

Comment: А вы  видите, что стоит одна запятая, а не две, то есть обособления здесь нет.  Вероятно, в устной речи делается пауза, поэтому мы видим необоснованную постановку лишней запятой. Так в чем заключается проблема "лишних запятых" и как  она решается? На этот вопрос следует ответить. Вы же дополняете предложение распространенным оборотом, но это уже не то предложение, о котором спрашивают.

Comment: Мой ответ был в том, что это ошибка. Пауза в речи обозначается троеточием.

Comment: Это вы у Розенталя прочитали или где? Дайте, пожалуйса, ссылку на источник.

Comment: Да, у Розенталя это есть. Можете посмотреть главу про многоточие.

Comment: Спасибо. Тогда такой вопрос. Розенталь часто говорит об интонационном предупреждении при постановке двоеточия. Что он имеет в виду?

Comment: Пауза – временной аспект речи. Она может быть обозначена запятой, тире, двоеточием, многоточием, точкой. Выбор того или иного знака зависит от смысла паузы. В том разделе у Розенталя ничего о паузе как таковой не сказано, а описываются случаи постановки многоточия.

Comment: Если это не пауза обусловленная синтаксисом, а просто умолкание на короткое время, то такая пауза обозначается многоточием. Здесь идет речь именно о такой паузе.

Comment: Просто фраза "Пауза в речи обозначается троеточием" без объяснения причины паузы выглядит очень категорично.

Comment: «Я был охвачен азартом, глаза мои горели, но я ... все проиграл.» Пауза по желанию говорящего или по эмоциональной боли, или заикание. Понятно, что речь идет о такой паузе.

Comment: Спасибо за труды, многоточие меня не очень интересует, речь в вопросе шла о паузе  в простом предложении.  А вы почитайте всё-таки Розенталя, он про интонацию часто упоминает  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#pp151 7. Перед второй частью бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится тире, если она (нередко — неполное предложение) имеет изъяснительное значение (перед ней можно вставить союз что), причем в первой части не содержится ИНТОНАЦИОННОГО предупреждения о последующем изложении какого-либо факта: Овца же говорит — она всю ночь спала (Кр.);

Comment: В справочнике Розенталя полно некачественных, размытых формулировок. Здесь как-раз одна из них. У меня нет особого желания расшифровывать это священное писание. Возможно, это высокий резки тон, говорящий о том, что последует важная, эпическая, захватывающая или изумляющая информация.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что у вас возникают вопросы о постановке двоеточия или тире при изъяснительных отношениях в бессоюзном предложении.

Comment: Ответ на комментарий я дам отдельно.

Answer (score 3):

Правильно:  ***Воздух рядом с ним // становится как мед.***

Некорректная постановка запятой в данном предложении объясняется общей проблемой **«лишних запятых».**

В простом  предложении даже при отсутствии знаков всегда есть хотя бы одна пауза. Мы всегда **тонируем нашу устную речь**, то есть первую часть предложения произносим с повышением тона, потом делаем **произносительную** паузу, а к концу понижаем тон. Такое деление делается по смыслу: о чем говорим (тема) и что говорим (сообщение по данной теме).

Данное предложение делится на группу подлежащего и группу сказуемого, но в общем случае оно **может быть и  другим**, например: *Рядом с этим удивительным человеком // даже воздух становится как мед.*

Произносительная пауза  обозначает только перелом интонации, она **не подчеркивается** в речи, не считается **грамматической** и знаками препинания не обозначается. В то же время она достаточно ясно ощущается, поэтому на этом месте иногда ошибочно ставится «лишняя запятая».

Comment: А по-моему, это все же тайный еврейский сигнал.